# Has xcode 4.5 changed sortedArrayUsingComparator + blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Just updated xcode to 4.5 and I'm receiving an error in one of my iOS apps which I wasn't getting previously. Problem was not occurring before the update.

Basically, I have an array that needs sorting, based on some other irrelevant tests..

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayFiles sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = [(PPFile*)a name];
    NSString *second = [(PPFile*)b name];

    if ([a isFileAvailableForRead] && ![b isFileAvailableForRead]) {

        return  NSOrderedAscending;
    }else if(![a isFileAvailableForRead] && [b isFileAvailableForRead]) {

        return  NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    return [first compare:second];

}];
```

The error is on the last return of the block:

```
     Return type 'NSComparisonResult' (aka 'enum NSComparisonResult') must match previous type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') when block literal has unspecified explicit return type
```

Thanks.

Comment: Xcode hadn't changed anything. It may only be the framework that changed the header files, but Xcode has **absolutely nothing to do with this.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the return value type:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayFiles sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    < your code>
}];
```

Comment: Cheers.. any idea why this didn't seem to occur in older versions?

Comment: I forgot to specify that ^(id a, id b) is interpreted like ^void (id,id) , but the parameter was of type ^ NSComparisonResult (id,id).