# Return type "NSComparaisonResult" after the XCode update

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I have a problem similar to the one outlined here:
[Has xcode 4.5 changed sortedArrayUsingComparator + blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548789/has-xcode-4-5-changed-sortedarrayusingcomparator-blocks)

```
int index = [AAjouter indexOfObject:match inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [AAjouter count]) options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex usingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {


Match *match1 = (Match *) obj1;
Match *match2 = (Match *) obj2;

if ([match1.matchDate isEqualToDate:match2.matchDate]) {
    if ([match1.paysCompetition isEqualToString:match2.paysCompetition]) {
        if ([[NSNumber numberWithInt:match1.ordreCompetition] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:match2.ordreCompetition]]) {
            if ([match1.equipeANom isEqualToString:match2.equipeANom]) {
                return NSOrderedSame;
            }
            else {
                return [match1.equipeANom compare:match2.equipeANom];
            }
        }
        else {
            return [[NSNumber numberWithInt:match1.ordreCompetition] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:match2.ordreCompetition]]; 
        }
    }
    else {
        return [match1.paysCompetition compare:match2.paysCompetition]; 
    }
} 
else {
    return [match1.matchDate compare:match2.matchDate];
}
```

}];

[AAjouter insertObject:match atIndex:index];
break;

I have this error message:

> "Return type 'NSComparaisonResult' (aka 'NSComparaisonResult') must
>   match previous return type 'NSIntger' (aka 'int')"

after each code line:

```
return [[NSNumber numberWithInt:match1.ordreCompetition] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:match2.ordreCompetition]]; 
return [match1.paysCompetition compare:match2.paysCompetition]; 
return [match1.matchDate compare:match2.matchDate];
```

Would you have an idea?

Comment: Looks like the method is declared as returning `int`, however you don't show it so I don't know for sure...

Comment: yip, likely it is declared as something in the header and something else in the m file

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly specify the return type:

```
^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) { ...
```

The compiler usually infers the return type of the block, but in some cases, it can get confused. I suspect it might have to do with returning the enum `NSOrderedSame`, which, on older versions of the compiler, would be type `int`.