# Compiler complains about mismatched types when calling sortedArrayUsingComparator

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
static NSArray *topologicallySortedReadableTypes;
static dispatch_once_t pred;

dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    topologicallySortedReadableTypes = [self readableTypes];
    topologicallySortedReadableTypes = [topologicallySortedReadableTypes sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id type1, id type2) {
        if (type1 == type2) return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        if (UTTypeConformsTo((CFStringRef)type1, (CFStringRef)type2)) return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        if (UTTypeConformsTo((CFStringRef)type2, (CFStringRef)type1)) return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        // the problem is right here
        return ((NSUInteger)type1 < (NSUInteger)type2) ? (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending : (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }];
});
```

This is the source code of textedit latest version provided by apple which is for 10.7. as apple didnt gave the source for 10.8, so it should work fine under 10.8. but it is giving an error that is,
**Return Type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') must match previous return type 'NSComparisonResult' (aka 'enum NSComparisonResult') when block literal has unspecified return type.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the compiler is now more strict/confused about block return types. This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324079/return-type-nscomparaisonresult-after-the-xcode-update) suggests to add the explicit return type to the comparison block:

```
topologicallySortedReadableTypes = [topologicallySortedReadableTypes
    sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id type1, id type2) {…}];
```

Comment: Hey, but its already there. in the start of the code, i think there's something wrong with the return type value. i've also tried simple if, else rather then ternary, but that didnt work either..

Comment: I didn’t mean the explicit cast in the return statement, I meant a return type annotation in the definition of the comparison block. It’s not there in the code sample you posted, do we understand each other?

Comment: Could you plz. tell me where to find comparison block? basically i didnt wrote this code, its a prewritten code by apple, you can find it in xcode documentation and search for textedit and go to sample code area and open it. when you simple hit run, it will give you this error.
Can you also tell me how to find blocks btw?

Comment: The sample code in my question is taken directly from your sample, compare it. There’s just one extra `NSComparisonResult` that should make the code compile.

Comment: Thanks mate. iTs solved my question! how to give points in stack overflow?

Comment: Great, happy to help. I recommend that you read the [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210) book by Apple, it should make your life easier in the long run. There should be a checkmark next to my answer that marks the answer as accepted, that will give extra 15 points to me and two points to you for accepting an answer. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.